# Task Item added event receiver does not fire when item is added by Nintex workflow SharePoint 2016

Tags: event-receivers, task-list, nintex

I am trying to add an event receiver on the workflow task - list Item Added event, to get the Task ID and update it on another SharePoint List.

This is because once I add an Assign Flexi Task action on the Nintex workflow, there is no way to get the created task ID in the workflow, unless someone actions on the task.

However, the Event Receiver on the Workflow Task list Item Added event does not fire!?

Can someone help me in solving this? or any alternative solution please.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved by Restarting the IIS and restarting the SharePoint Timer Process.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that one of these is true:

1. New solution was not deployed correctly.
2. The event receive is not registered correctly.
3. You din't restart app pool or IIS.
4. Nintext [blocks event receivers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-insider/gjckpigahcbffmeofjfedlffddhfidhj?hl=en) when creating a task.

The first step is to conirm that you have event receiver registered. To do it:

- Install [SP Insider chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-insider/gjckpigahcbffmeofjfedlffddhfidhj?hl=en)
- Navigate to your SharePoint site
- Click SP Insider extension:

[image]

- Click Find current web
- Locate EventReceivers for your list/library

[image]

- Verify that A) Event receiver exinsts and B) It has correct Synchronization type